# Date format validation to be dd/mm/yyyy only

Tags: date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Jquery datepicker which selects the value in dd/mm/yyyy format. But if the date selected is then edited to a wrong format other than dd/mm/yyyy then I need to display a validation error message that the date should be in dd/mm/yyyy format. Please help with this. the entered date should be dd/mm/yyyy format only. what is the logic or regex to compare the date format?

Comment: I got the regex for mm/dd/yyyy ^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$ but i need for dd/mm/yyyy. I edited this but not working fr dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Where's your code?

According to the docs (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker):

it says you update time format like this: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );`

Comment: no matter what end user inputs i need to validate it to dd/mm/yyyy format. I will be then displaying an error messsage

Comment: yes, you can make the format whatever you want. my point was that you should look at the documentation, AND supply us your code so we can see what it is you've got currently.